@intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n imports locales json files in weird structure
I would like to internationalize a simple vue application and I utilized vue-i18n and unplugin-vue-i18n. I expect the following snippet in vue 3 api composition renders the word John:
<template>
   ...
   <h2>{{ $tm('name') }}</h2>
   ...
<template>

but it returns weird json string as follows:
{ "type": 0, "start": 0, "end": 3, "loc": { "start": { "line": 1, "column": 1, "offset": 0 }, "end": { "line": 1, "column": 4, "offset": 3 }, "source": "John" }, "body": { "type": 2, "start": 0, "end": 3, "loc": { "start": { "line": 1, "column": 1, "offset": 0 }, "end": { "line": 1, "column": 4, "offset": 3 } }, "items": [ { "type": 3, "start": 0, "end": 3, "loc": { "start": { "line": 1, "column": 1, "offset": 0 }, "end": { "line": 1, "column": 4, "offset": 3 } } } ], "static": "John" } }

Here are the config files:


package.json:
...
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/vue": "^1.7.23",
    "@intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n": "^5.2.0",
    "pinia": "^2.1.7",
    "vue": "^3.5.9",
    "vue-i18n": "^9.14.1",
    "vue-router": "^4.3.3"
  },
...

vite.config.ts:
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'
import { resolve, dirname } from "node:path";
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import VueI18nPlugin from "@intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n/vite";

export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    port: 5174
  },
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    VueI18nPlugin({
      // runtimeOnly: false,
      include: resolve(dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)), './src/locales/**'),
      // strictMessage: false
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
})

main.ts:
import './assets/main.css';

import { createApp } from 'vue';
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n';
import { createPinia } from 'pinia';

import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import messages from '@intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n/messages';

const i18n = createI18n({
  legacy: false,
  globalInjection: true,
  locale: "en",
  fallbackLocale: "en",
  availableLocales: ["en", "fi"],
   messages
});

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(i18n)
app.use(createPinia())
app.use(router)

app.mount('#app')

and en.json file:
{
  "name": "John"
}

Would someone please help me to fix it.
Update:

I've created project using the following commands (for reproducing the problom)
npm init vue@latest test
npm install vue-i18n@latest @intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n@latest

Then I set the above configuration.
That's it.
Also I did according to this and this articles.

This is what compiled messages look like. They aren't intended to be used directly. " it returns weird json string" - by using $tm('name')? This shouldn't happen. Please, provide a way to reproduce, this is specific to your case and needs to be debugged. How do you know the problem is unplugin-vue-i18n? Did you try to do the same thing without it with other result?

When I remove the unplugin-vue-i18n it works as expected. I mean if I provide translations directly in `main.ts', it will work. Whole configuration posted in the question and there is nothing more.

Make sure it's reproducible. Providing a demo will increase your chance to solve the problem, because you're using relatively unpopular library that works in magical and undocumented ways, this may require to check what happens. But currently it looks like the problem is with compiled messages in general. t's unclear what's the intention of using $tm here. It's supposed to be used with rt(), https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/api/composition#tm-key . This is probably the only fix that is needed

Thanks for your answer - According to [official intlify guide] (https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/migration/breaking#translation-api-return-value), I used $tm(). and rt() function returns the key instead of value. I update the question that how I scaffold the project.

Can you clarify your concerns about rt()? It's intended for this purpose exactly. tm() returns message object, not actual translation. It needs to be processed by rt(). It's unknown why you use tm in the first place, but the correct use for it that works well with compiled messages is what the docs show

As I said in the recent comment, rt() does not work correctly. I put the sample on the GitHub. Could you please take a look or clone it and help me to fix the problem. (please see HelloWorld.vue)

As explained in the documentation, tm returns a message which needs to be resolved to a string with rt. This can be optional when a message is a string, but this isn't so when they are compiled at build time with @intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n
The correct usage is:
$rt($tm('name'))

Despite that tm correctly returns compiled message object that is listed in the question, it's not recognized by rt, this causes this error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Not support non-string message
    at createCompileError (message-compiler.esm-browser.js:116:19)
    at createCoreError (core-base.mjs:485:12)
    at compileToFunction (core-base.mjs:1008:15)
    at compileMessageFormat (core-base.mjs:1324:17)
    at translate (core-base.mjs:1168:11)
    at vue-i18n.mjs:559:48
    at wrapWithDeps (vue-i18n.mjs:504:19)
    at t (vue-i18n.mjs:559:16)
    at Proxy.rt (vue-i18n.mjs:567:16)
    at Proxy._sfc_render (HelloWorld.vue:10:17)

The problem here is version mismatch. Despite that this doesn't seem to be mentioned in the documentation, and major versions of @intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n and vue-i18n aren't synchronized, the timeline of new version releases is similar. It should be either @intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n@5 and vue-i18n@10, or @intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n@4 and vue-i18n@9, then it becomes workable. Since both major versions of the packages have just been released, this could be a bug.

I appreciate your answer, but suggested versions had no correct result, I don't want bother you any more, I consider using vue-i18n without @intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n and I will give it another try after a while, hoping the bug will be fixed.

@Askar Can you clarify what was the problem? I was able to reproduce it in the repo you posted, and a combination of 10+5 and 9+4 were workable for the said usage, $rt($tm('name'))

I had utilized the suggested versions on our main project and the application did not work at all, probably because of a conflict between @intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n and one of the other plugins. After your recent comment, I tested the suggested version on the sample one which I put on GitHub and I experienced the correct behavior of the plugin. Both (vue-i18n@10.0.3 - @intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n@5.2.0) and (vue-i18n@9.1.14 - @intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n@4.0.0) worked on the sample one. I want to thank you for your help again.

Glad this helped.
